# Jersey Rest - how to indent json output based on request param?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have a requirement to prettify json based on request param. if prettify request param is true then indent json output. Is there a way to inject this param to Jersey and indent automatically.

Here is the sample method of my rest service

```
@Path("/{manageElement}")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Object update(@Context SecurityContext context,
        @PathParam(MANAGED_ELEMENET) String manageElement, @QueryParam("prettify") boolean prettyOutput, String content) {
    LOG.debug("started update.");

    Request request = new Request();
    request.setActionType(ActionType.UPDATE_ME);
    request.setRequestBody(content);
    request.setManageElement(manageElement);
    request.setRequester(GENERIC_USER);

    return service.service(request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using the default serializer/deserializer with Jersey, you can change it once it's created. It's registered at startup, but you could use your own serializer/deserializer and return the response something like this. I have mostly used Gson in the past:

```
@Path("/{manageElement}")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Object update(@Context SecurityContext context,
                     @PathParam(MANAGED_ELEMENET) String manageElement, @QueryParam("prettify") boolean prettyOutput, String content) {

    Request request = new Request();
    request.setActionType(ActionType.UPDATE_ME);
    request.setRequestBody(content);
    request.setManageElement(manageElement);
    request.setRequester(GENERIC_USER);

    if(prettyOutput) {
        Object response = service.service(request);
        String resp = getPrettyGson().toJson(response);
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(resp).build();

    }
    else {
        Object response = service.service(request);
        String resp = getGson().toJson(response);
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(resp).build();
    }

}

private Gson getPrettyGson() {
    return new GsonBuilder()
            .setPrettyPrinting()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
            .create();
}

private Gson getGson() {
    return new GsonBuilder()
                .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                .create();
}
```

There is an example in the jersey examples that does show how to register a custom provider but no indication of changing it a runtime: [jersey doc](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.19/examples/json-jackson/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/examples/jackson/MyObjectMapperProvider.java)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your using Jackson, you can just configure two different `ObjectMapper`s in a [`ContextResolver`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ContextResolver.html), and determine the mapper to use based on the query parameter. Kind of like seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31828603/2587435).

The linked answer tries to get the path parameters, but to get the query parameter, just use

```
String param = uriInfo.getQueryParameters().getFirst("prettify");
if (param != null) { 
    boolean prettify = Boolean.valueOf(param);
    if (prettify) return prettifyMapper;
}
return regularMapper;
```

To get formatted output with Jackson, depending on which version you can do:

Jackson 1.x

```
ObjectMapper prettifyMapper = new ObjectMapper();
prettifyMapper.enable(SerializationConfig.Feature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
```

Jackson 2.x

```
ObjectMapper prettifyMapper = new ObjectMapper();
prettifyMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
```